# How to get value as type Number on this.formgroup.value()?

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, formgroups

The value I get on submitting a form group is

```
{
  "name": "Sunil",
  "age": "23"
}
```

What I want is

```
{
  "name": "Sunil",
  "age": 23
}
```

My form group is as follows in my .ts file

```
myForm : FormGroup;
this.myForm = this._formbuilder.group({
  name: [''],
  age: [null]
});
```

Comment: `+this.myForm.get('age').value` . Use `+` to cast in number

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Is there no inbuilt way for angular to using validators or something?

Comment: you can add validator on every control, you can  `import { Validators } from '@angular/forms'`. For example, if you want the control to be required, you can add an array of validators while you build your form`name: ['', [Validators.required]]`. The best way is to check documentation : https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators try to implement it and open a specific question if you can't make it

Comment: @Floiran where should I add this line on the code?

Answer (score 18):

Convert it before sending it.

```
const value = { ...this.myForm.value, age: +this.myForm.value.age };
```

Or you can use an input of type number.

```
<input type="number" formControlName="age">
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Is there no inbuilt way for angular to using validators or something?

Comment: @SunilBehera you can add Validators.pattern to age form control

Comment: @SunilBehera `input type="number"` is already validating that it is a number. You can still create your own with `NaN` or using a regex pattern.

Comment: Validators too returns value as string

Comment: No, I'm saying you should validate that your string can be converted to number, but yeah, validators won't change your data type.

Comment: Adding the `type="number"` fixed the issue for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This just another solution power by `rxjs` , simply convert input string value to number value on `valueChanges`

```
const ageFormControl = this.myForm.get('age');

ageFormControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(distinct())
  .subscribe(value => ageFormControl.setValue(+value));
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53590931)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there anyway angular provide inbuilt without using pipes

Comment: you can't use angular pipe like number with input element  